# PSQL - Find the count of tables in a Postgres database for all schemas where table name starting or ending with temp keyword

Tags: sql, postgresql, schema, psql

How to count the number of tables in a Postgres database for all schemas where table name starting or ending with temp?
currently I am using

\dt *.*temp*

which is giving me output of all tables. but rather I just need count of the table in the DB.

Comment: I don't need the row count  in a table. I want the table count in all schemes of the DB where table_name LIKE %temp%. Please suggest

Comment: `select count(*) from information_schema.tables where ...`?